# Unable to sort objects read from a file in C++

Tags: c++, class, sorting, object, file-handling

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#define MAX 30
using namespace std;
int n, i, j, ch;
char ans;
fstream file;
```

Hey guys, below I have created a class to maintain records of students.

```
class student
{
  char name[20];
public:
  int rln;
  void get()
  {
    cout<<"\nEnter name: ";
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"\nEnter roll no.: ";
    cin>>rln;
  }
  void show()
  {
    cout << right << setw(20) << name << "   " << setw(10) << rln << "\n";
  }
};
```

Below, I create two objects: one as an array to sort by roll numbers of students, the other as a temporary holding object.

```
student s[MAX], u;
```

The below function is used to sort out an array of objects based on their roll numbers parameter

```
void bubble_sort(student s[])
{
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)
    {
      if(s[j].rln>s[j+1].rln)
      {
        cout<<"\nHi";
        student temp;
        temp=s[j];
        s[j]=s[j+1];
        s[j+1]=temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the main function

```
int main()
{
```

Here, I can't choose 1st option as  first we must create a file holding records.

```
  cout<<"1.Sort existing file records"
      <<"\n2.Create and sort new set of records"
      <<"\n";
  cin>>ch;


  switch(ch)
  {
    case 1:
    {
      file.open("unsort.txt", ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out);
```

NOTE: Due to uncertainty, I'm reading only 3 records from file, but I will increase that number later. I know I could have used a while loop, but let's just say I want to read only 3 records.
Reading each record into temporary object 'u' and inserting it into the array object 's[i]'

```
      for(i=0; i<3; i++)
      {
        file.read((char *)&u, sizeof(u));
        s[i]=u;
      }
```

The display part:

```
      cout<<"\nLook what I found!:\n";
      cout << right << setw(20) << "Name" << "   " << setw(10) << "Roll number\n";
  for(i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    s[i].show();
  }
  file.close();
  break;
}
```

Case 2 for creating new records, pretty much samelike case 1...Except that I'm truncating the unsorted file first...

```
case 2:
{
  file.open("unsort.txt", ios::binary|ios::trunc|ios::out);
  cout<<"\nNumber of records: ";
  cin>>n;
  for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    u.get();
    s[i]=u;
    file.write((char *)&u, sizeof(u));
  }
  file.close();
  cout<<"\nYour input:\n";
  cout << right << setw(20) << "Name" << "   " << setw(10) << "Roll number\n";
      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
        s[i].show();
      }
      break;
    }
  }
```

The sorting goes like this:

```
  cout<<"\nChoose sorting method:"
      <<"\n1.Bubble Sort"
      <<"\n";
  cin>>ch;
```

In case 1, I've opened a new file to store sorted records- please note that:

```
  switch(ch)
  {
    case 1:
    {
      file.open("sort.txt", ios::binary|ios::trunc|ios::out);
```

Then, I call bubble_sort function with the 's' array to be sorted:

```
      bubble_sort(s);
      cout<<"\nSorted:\n";
      cout << right << setw(20) << "Name" << "   " << setw(10) << "Roll number\n";
```

IMPORTANT PART: Hopefully, this sorting works perfectly for Case 2, i.e. for newly created records. But it doesn't output anything when reading from previously stored unsorted records file. What is wrong?

```
      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
        s[i].show();
        file.write((char *)&s[i], sizeof(s[i]));
      }
      file.close();
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use global `std::fstream` object, instead create local one where it is needed. It will make your program cleaner and make your problem gone.

Comment: I'm so sorry for the really long post, but I am new to this community and didn't know what parts I could have cut off.

Comment: @Slava local std::fstream objects as in for each switch case?

Comment: Yes and not `std::fstream` but `std::ifstream` where you need input and `std::ofstream` where you need output.

Comment: Instead of `file.open("unsort.txt", ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out);` you would have `std::ifstream file("unsort.txt", ios::binary|ios::in);` and you do not have to close it explicitly, destructor would take care of it.

Comment: @Slava Sorry, but I tried that and yet somehow the bubble sort just isn't reaching after selecting the read option, because if the bubble sort would have reached it would have atleast given one output as "Hi" which I placed in there.

Comment: It would give you `Hi` if condition was met, I cannot debug your program for you

Comment: @Slava But all the conditions do match, right?

Comment: How would I know, I do not have your data.

Comment: @Slava Actually, the above code is all there is. And the only data would be three names and their associated numbers.

Comment: And? If this condition `if(s[j].rln>s[j+1].rln)` would be true or not depend on data you have in your file. Depends on that you would get "Hi" message or not. Is that not clear?

Comment: @Slava Yes you're right. So, I moved the 'cout<<"Hi";' outside the if loop, into the for loop. But it's still not displaying even one iteration of it.

Comment: Welcome to debugging! First step of avoiding error in your program - make it readable. For example your splitting code make it unreadable for me, and I am not going to bother and assemble it back into one piece.

Comment: @Slava I'm sorry. Do you want me to put one piece of the whole code? I thought snippets were the norm. Though I put them in parts in their order

Comment: I do not want anything from you. It is in your interest to make it readable for others. Try to read and comprehend your own code here by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variables are easy to forget. Here in case 1, n is not initialized to the number of records and keeps its initialization value of 0. So you sort and display an empty array.

Just changing the read part to:

```
  for(i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    file.read((char *)&u, sizeof(u));
    s[i]=u;
  }
  n = 3;   // <- do not forget it!
```

is enough to get rid of the problem.

But my advice is to remove the global variable and pass it explicitely to the sort function.

Comment: Hey Serge Ballesta, your solution totally did the trick! Thanks a lot! You and @Slava really helped me understand C++ a little more